# Sdcard readable but not readable on my computer... but readable from my camera

Tags: mount, sd-card

I have an Sdcard that I use in a camera. From the camera, I can take pictures, remove files... But from my computer (debian unstable) I can only read, but not write. Note that this strange things appeared quite recently, maybe a few weeks ago. Note that I used the camera tools to format the SD card, and that magic lantern is installed on it (don't think it matters anyway).

On linux, if I try to force to remount the partition as read/write, I get the following error:

```
$ sudo mount -rw -o remount /dev/mmcblk0p1
mount: /media/me/EOS_DIGITAL: /dev/mmcblk0p1 is write-protected but explicit read-write mode requested.
```

Note that it is *not* a locker issue, as I tried to change the locker position, and moreover, the sdcard is still readable on the camera.

Any idea? Thanks!

PS: if your method can harm data on the SD card, please let me know before so that I find a way to backup first!

Comment: Have you tried a different reader? Perhaps the sensor in the reader that reads the state of the physical write lock (the lock is not actually electrically connected inside the card itself) is failing, and is always reporting the card as read-only.

Comment: "_the sdcard is still readable on the camera_" doesn't confirm the earlier statement that, "_it is_ not _a locker issue_" because you're not testing the write function in the camera.

Comment: @roaima "From the camera, I can take pictures, *remove files*", the OP said, so writing is tested in the camera, **but** those cameras often don't check the WP pin anyhow, so you are right in the end: It still can be a locker issue.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. So I tried again, and after some times I realized that the problem is indeed from my reader: depending on the angle I use when I insert the card, it may mount the card as read only or read/write. So I guess the reader miss reads sometimes the PW pin. I really think it's stupid to have a software lock instead of a physical lock, but anyway... Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

## To solve the issue

Every time i met this kind of problem (external flash drive / SD Card /... mounting read-only under Linux) it was because the FAT filesystem wasn't properly unmouted and had errors.
Putting it on a windows system (so that windows repaired it) or using `fsck.fat` on it solved the issue.
Take care using `fsck.fat` since it may harm your SD card.

## Backing up the SD card

Simply use `dd if=<your sdcard device, ie: /dev/sdb> of=backup.sdcard` to backup your whole SD card.
Then you could mount it later simply using:

1. If there's no partition table but directly the fat on it:  `mount -o loop backup.sdcard mountpoint/`
2. If there's partition table, you will have to compute the offset before. For example:

   ```
   $ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
   Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
   Disklabel type: dos
   Disk identifier: 0xe9a3179f

   Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
   /dev/sda1  *      2048    499711    497664   243M 83 Linux
   /dev/sda2       501758 500117503 499615746 238.2G  5 Extended
   /dev/sda5       501760 500117503 499615744 238.2G 83 Linux
   ```

To mount the sda partition, which starts at 501758, i have to apply a `block_size * 501758` offset:

`mount -o loop,offset=$((512*501758)) /dev/sda mountpoint`

Comment: Sorry for my time to answer, but I couldn't make any backup before due to lack of space available. So I tried `fsck.vfat /dev/mmcblk0p1`, but I get an error `fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24) open: Read-only file system`

Comment: Ohhh.... I think I got it: depending on the angle I use when I insert the SD card, it is sometimes mounted read only, sometimes read/write! So I guess my reader sometimes miss reads the WP pin... Thanks!